# How to compile an application against the static OpenSSL library?

Tags: openssl, linker

I have an application that I want to link statically to the OpenSSL library (because the OS-provided version is too old).

I have built the OpenSSL library for this device (it is an old ARM embedded device), and linking against the `.so` files works fine:

```
~$ /usr/local/arm-linux/bin/arm-linux-gcc «my own objects» -ldl  -lresolv -lsms -lssl -Wall -o «binary»
```

Now, I want to build against the `.a` files, but I don't seem to get the right command. The best I get it this:

```
~$ /usr/local/arm-linux/bin/arm-linux-gcc «my own objects» -ldl  -lresolv -lsms -Wall /usr/local/arm-linux/lib/libssl.a /usr/local/arm-linux/lib/libcrypto.a -o «binary»
```

But, this gives the following unfound references:

```
digest.o(.text+0x48): In function `digest_get_hash':
: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_crypto'
digest.o(.text+0x78): In function `digest_get_hash':
: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_new'
digest.o(.text+0xf4): In function `digest_get_hash':
: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_CTX_free'
ssl.o(.text+0x1c): In function `_ssl_initialise_context':
: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_crypto'
ssl.o(.text+0x2c): In function `_ssl_initialise_context':
: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
ssl.o(.text+0x30): In function `_ssl_initialise_context':
: undefined reference to `TLS_client_method'
ssl.o(.text+0xc0): In function `ssl_init':
: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_ssl'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Different commands, in where I change the order, or plainly leave out `libcrypto.a` or `libssl.a` yield different results (all undefined references).

How can I link statically against the OpenSSL `.a` libraries?

**Update** When I unpack the `.a` files using `ar x «library.a»`, and link against the resulting `.o` files, the build succeeds.

**Update** This is the output of `gcc -v`:

```
[bf@localhost src]$ /usr/local/arm-linux/bin/arm-linux-gcc -v
Reading specs from /usr/local/arm-linux/bin/../lib/gcc-lib/arm-linux/3.3.2/specs
Configured with: ../configure --target=arm-linux --disable-shared --with-headers=/home/gerg/new-wave.xscale/linux-2.4.x/include --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --enable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.3.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I link statically against the OpenSSL .a libraries?

Your library order is wrong: `libcrypto.a` depends on `libssl.a`, so it *must* be listed before `libssl.a` on the link line.

See [this post](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking) for detailed explanation.

Comment: I just checked, but that didn't work. I still get some undefined references. I updated my question with the output from `gcc -v`.

Comment: From the link you provided, it says the exact opposite: "If object or library AA needs a symbol from library BB, then AA should come before library BB in the command-line invocation of the linker.". And when I put it in this order: `objects libssl libcrypto`, it builds. Because ssl depends on crypto.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Your comments confuse me: your original question has `libssl.a` `libcrypto.a` and produced errors. Now you claim that `objects libssl libcrypto` builds. Which way is it?

Comment: No idea. I guess I tried so many things and after reading the article you mentioned I tried again (understanding what I was doing) and it worked. I think (looking at my question) I was using the incorrect `.a` files (older ones). You helped me nonetheless, so thanks for that :).